# Добрый день реализовал у себя на блоге toggl день/ночь

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, веб-программирование

реализовал у себя на блоге toggl день/ночь. В **#main** при клике на него почему то перенаправляет на вверх на **header**.

> [Link original code](https://codepen.io/jesperkc/pen/pydMqb)

Уже целый день мучаюсь, не как не могу решить этот ребус. Сам свайп функцию выполняет, но при клике на него направляет в самый вверх сайта.

**Кнопка день/ночь**
[image: Кнопка день/ночь]

**При клике на кнопку направляет вверх шапки**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$('#toggle-box-checkbox').on('change', function(){
  if(this.checked){
    $('#main').addClass('night');
  }else{
    $('#main').removeClass('night');
  }
});





// run demo if in searchresult preview
function demo(){
    setInterval(function(){
      $("#toggle-box-checkbox").trigger('click');
    }, 1000);
}
if (document.location.pathname.indexOf('fullcpgrid')>-1){
  demo();
}
```

```css
/* main */

#main {
  float: left;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  border-top: 2px solid silver;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 30%, #88D9FF, #24206C, #222 80%);
    color: #333;
    background-size: 100% 400%;
    background-position: 100% 0%;
    transition: all 1s;
}

#main.night {
    background-position: 100% 100%;
    color: #fff; }

@media (min-width: 1401px) {
  #main {
    padding: 100px 20%;
    width: 60%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1400px) {
  #main {
    padding: 100px 10%;
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  #main div {
    width: 98%!important;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

#main div {
  width: 48%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  float: left;
}

#main h2 {font-size: 3em}
#main span {color: #a0a0a0}


/* toggl */
.toggle-box {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.toggle-box-label-left:empty {
    margin-left: -10px;
}

.toggle-box-label-left:before,
.toggle-box-label-left:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  /*transition*/
    -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
    outline: none;
}

.toggle-box input[type=checkbox],
.toggle-box input[type=checkbox]:active {
    position: absolute;
    top: -5000px;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

.toggle-box label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: rgba(149, 149, 149, 0.51);
    font-weight: normal;
}

.toggle-box-label-left:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    line-height: 34px;
    text-indent: 40px;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    margin: 4px;
  /*border-radius*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    right: 26px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: #FFB200;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
}

.toggle-box-label-left:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 24px;
  /*border-radius*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
    -moz-border-radius: 16px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 10px;
    border: 2px solid #FFB200;
}

.toggle-box input[type=checkbox]:checked + .toggle-box-label-left:before {
  /*left: -70%;*/
    right: 17px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 0 #eee;
    background: transparent;
}

.toggle-box input[type=checkbox]:checked + .toggle-box-label-left:after {
  left: -70%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border: 2px solid white;
}

.toggle-box input[type=checkbox] + .toggle-box-label-left {
  /*top: -65px;*/
  /*left: -70%;*/
    color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.51);
    font-weight: bold;
}

.toggle-box input[type=checkbox]:checked + .toggle-box-label-left {
  /*top: -65px;*/
  /*left: -70%;*/
    color: rgba(149, 149, 149, 0.51);
    font-weight: normal;
}

.toggle-box input[type=checkbox]:checked + .toggle-box-label-left + .toggle-box-label {
  /*top: -65px;*/
  /*left: -70%;*/
  color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.51);
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-box">
  <div id="main">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1"  id="toggle-box-checkbox"/>
    <label for="toggle-box-checkbox"  class="toggle-box-label-left"></label>
    <label for="toggle-box-checkbox"  class="toggle-box-label"></label>
    <div class="intro">
      <h2>Key information</h2>
      <span>Большой выбор всего, что может вам пригодиться</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos impedit, ut vero commodi voluptate? Ipsam reiciendis, necessitatibus incidunt ipsa quis sapiente excepturi, optio iusto voluptatibus dolorem officia quidem, numquam eaque minus, autem praesentium rem architecto dolores. Ipsa unde id velit optio magni enim! Illum obcaecati, dolorem distinctio nemo, ipsum iure.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Ваша проблема вот здесь:

```
.toggle-box input[type=checkbox],
.toggle-box input[type=checkbox]:active {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5000px;
  ...
}
```

При изменении состояния с/на `:active` браузер пересчитывает позицию и дергает документом.

В вашем случае можно решить гораздо проще и заодно оптимизировать как минимум две вещи:

1. чекбокс не надо насиловать прозрачностью и позиционированием. Просто поставьте ему `display:none` - работать он от этого не перестанет. К тому же с точки зрения производительности этот стиль раз в сто эффективнее (конечно, юзер это вряд ли заметит, но представьте, что у вас таблица с десятью тысячами строк, в каждой из которых подобный чекбокс...).
2. применять скрипты, да еще с фреймворками там, где можно решить голым CSS - моветон. В вашем случае можно вынести чекбокс за пределы #main (перед ним;  трогать не надо) и вместо класса .night использовать стиль `#toggle-box-checkbox:checked + #main {styles for night theme}`. И всё. Без скриптов.

Comment: Спасибо друг "Во славу инквизиции и Тзинча! " хотел уточнить на счет скрипта, то есть єтот код можно использовать без js и он будет работать ?

Comment: конечно.  это просто css, читается как "применить к элементу #main, который следует за ЧЕКНУТЫМ элементом #toggle-box-checkbox такие-то стиля".  ну и так же стилятся все потомки и "младшие братья" #main. единственный момент - лучше навешивать стиля не на id а на классы - актуально, например, когда не сам полностью код контролируешь, а используешь какой-нибудь фреймворк/cms/платформу